# python script to check between 10pm and 9am

Tags: python, events, time

I have a python script that monitors the gates on my fence so I know when they are opened (garage doors too). The script will send me one text message any time a gate or garage door is opened or closed.. 
I also have a crontab job that checks all of them before bed so I know if I left them open or not..

What I want to do...

If it's after 10pm and before 9am I want the script to call a different python script that will text bomb me (and my father-in-law) every couple of seconds so we know someone has opened one of my fence gates.

I'm not a great coder but I know how to call a different script and I know how to make the script text bomb me.. I DON'T know how to make the script check to see if the time is between 10pm and 9am ..

Any help would be awesome!

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a module such as `time` or `datetime`.

For example, if it's 8pm, doing `time.localtime()` will return something like:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=20, 
                 tm_min=8, tm_sec=37, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=258, tm_isdst=1)
```

You can then use the `tm_hour` and `tm_min` attributes of the returned object to find the local hour and minute (in military time):

```
now = time.localtime()
if now.tm_hour >= 22 or now.tm_hour < 9:
    text_bomb()
```

You could then organize your gate-checking code so that if the time it's triggered falls between your specified range, it will launch the text-message-spamming code.

Comment: @user2782497 -- No problem! If this answer worked for you, click the checkmark to the left of my answer to let others know that your problem has been solved.